# Magento 2 Cart Price Rule -"Category does not contain" not working

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.7

i have created cart price rule to give 10 percent off ,but have excluded few category as shown in screenshot , but does not works properly and 10 pc discount is applied for product category excluded also , please check if i am doing something wrong

[image]

Comment: have found any solution ??